# Walk through list using elements, but not losing elements Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am looking for a way of walking through a list, grabbing an element (in that order its given I suppose), using it with another function, then returning to that list and continuing the operation WITHOUT losing that element from the list.

In examples I've seen the only way to accomplish this would be to do the following:

```
counter :: (Eq a1, Num a) => a1 -> [a1] -> a
counter a []            = 0
counter a [x]           = if a == x then 1 else 0
counter a (x:xs)        = if a == x then counter a xs + 1 else counter a xs


permut :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
permut [] []            = True
permut [x] []           = False
```

But this gets rid of the element x from the list xs when called again both within permut. I know that this also serves to end the recursive calls/terminate the function, but I need to have the whole list available in my counter function in order for it to work. I want to simply walk through the list and keep the whole thing intact. Is this possible?

EDIT: Updated use case. I am trying to work on checking if one list is a permutation of another. My thought process is within each list two properties will hold if they are a permutation:

1. They will have the same number of total elements (will implement this piece later)
2. They will have the same number of each element

Right now my counter function works, but I am losing elements as I iterate recursively through the permut function. I don't care about efficiency, I don't mind counting the same element again and comparing it if the number shows up in the list multiple times.

Comment: Can you give us a use case? Your description is too abstract, for me anyway.

Comment: Just pass the same list into 2 arguments? And keep the 2nd one unchanged during recursion.

Comment: @Ingo I've provided the specific use case I'm trying to work

Comment: @KennyTM not a bad idea by any means, but I'm curious if there is any other way to work around this in Haskell?

Comment: Ahhh, now so I see what you mena by "loosing elements". The point is you check only the first element of the left list. You need to do it for all elements in the left list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern match is a bit too exhaustive, and you need to check your condition for all elements. It should look like:

```
permut [] ys = null ys
permut xs ys = all condition xs
  where
    condition x = ....
```

Bonus suggestion: Whenever it is the case that it is true that you find yourself writing

```
if ..... then True else False
```

you write to much.

----- Addendum:

So you found `all`, it *does* walk through the list (xs in our case) and it checks if the condition is True for all elements (of xs in our case). For example:

```
all even [1,2,3]
```

is a short way to say:

```
even 1 && even 2 && even 3
```

So, in your where clause you have `condition`, and it has access to the original xs and ys lists, and it is called for each element in xs. Hence, all you need to check is if the argument x of `condition` occurs the same number of times in xs and ys. For this, you have already `counter`, so it'll be a one liner.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused... I get that I will then have my complete list of xs and ys to call counter on, but how can I "walk" through the list at all using the where clause? Side note, could you explain the use of null and all in your function- I've never seen them

Comment: I think I've found all and null appropriately. Makes sense, but the heart of my issue is still prevalent which is walking through the list. Condition will get the whole list xs, and I can pass it the whole list ys but how can I then start walking through the list. Counter requires a single element and then the entire list. If I write it condition x = counter x ys it will have both lists completely not just a single element

Comment: I added more explanation.

Comment: Great explanations! I just didn't understand how to use all to my advantage. That did the trick!

Comment: "Whenever it is the case that it is true that you find yourself writing..." I see what you did there :)